# grails multiple select: values are not stored in related object

Tags: select, grails, multi-select

I have a multiple select as follows:

```
<g:select name="receiptItems" from="${HealthService.findAllByDoctor(Doctor.findBySecUser(new ReceiptController().getCurrentlyLoggedUser()))}"
              multiple="multiple" optionKey="id"
              optionValue="${{it.healthServiceType.healthService}}"
              size="5" value="${receiptInstance?.healthServices*.id}" class="many-to-many"
              onchange="${remoteFunction(
                      controller: 'Receipt',
                      action: 'sumReceiptItems',
                      params: '\'receiptItemsSelected=\' + jQuery(this).val()',
                      onSuccess: 'updateTotalAmount(\'totalAmount\', data, \'00000\')')}"/>
```

After each selection, with the `remoteFunction`, a method from controller is called to do some calculation and update the totalAmount field. It works well but, when `save` method is called, `healthServices` field is null...and I don't understand why.
I've tried also with

```
receiptInstance?.healthServices.collect{it.id}
```

but I have the same result.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You named the select tag "**receiptItems**", so in the Controller inspect that parameter and then add it to the *receiptInstance*:

```
params?.receiptItems?.each {
    def service = HealthService.get(it)
    receiptInstance.addToHealthServices(service)
}
```

Comment: Where in particular in the controller?

Comment: inside of your _save()_ method before you save the receiptInstance