# grails: change value of hasMany object

Tags: select, grails, has-many

I've tried to change the hasMany value of an object and now it does not work anymore.
The hasMany was like

```
@NotNull
static hasMany = [receiptItems:ReceiptItem]
```

and now is like

```
 @NotNull
static hasMany = [healthServices:HealthService]
```

the value is linked to a multiple select (that I change only in the variable names). `healthServices` now is not filled with data after clicking on Save button.

Is there a proper way to change the value of a hasMany directive? Why do I have this kind of behaviour?

Comment: Share you both Domain Classes... Also share the error log, if any

Comment: I've seen that, changing the Class, I need to add something like described in the following SO post to allow the addition of healthservices: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20921407/grails-multiple-select-values-are-not-stored-in-related-object Why is this needed? Noone had the same behaviour?